# Proving that $f|\mathbb R \times \{0\}$ having a minimum and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0) > 0$ leads to $f$ having a minimum

Tags: real-analysis

I am given a function $f\in C^1(\mathbb R  \times \mathbb R_0^+)$ and I know that the restricted function $f|\mathbb R \times \{0\}$ has a local minimum at $(0,0)$. I also know that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0) > 0$. I would now like to show that $f$ itself has a local minimum in $(0,0)$. I already toyed around with the hint that suggests to compare $f(x,y)$ with $f(x,0)$ and $f(x,0)$ with $f(0,0)$.

I started off by saying that $\nabla f(x_0,0) = \nabla f|[\mathbb R \times \{0\}](x_0,0)$, so if I am not totally wrong, then I can conclude that $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) = 0$. What kind of irritates me though, is that I do not quite understand how $f$ can have an extremum at $(0,0)$, if  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0) > 0$. Doesn't it have to be zero as well? If not, how would I prove this statement?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $f$ is limited (there is a wall) on the negative values of $y$, so it is not mandatory to have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$.

For instance let consider $g(x)=x$ in the plane on the interval $[2,3]$. Clearly $g$'s minimum is in $x=2$, yet $g'(2)=1\neq 0$.

As an example let's look at $f(x,y)=(y+1)(x^2+1)$ on $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R^+$, it verifies your hypothesis and I'm sure you can easily visualize that $f$ has a local minimum in $(0,0)$ (it is even global in that case). But it would not be so if $y$ was allowed to be negative.

---

Another example, this time on the restriction in $\{0\}$, note that in your hypothesis $f$ is $C^1$ only for $y\neq 0$. [I assume the notation $\mathbb R_0$ stands for the usual $\mathbb R^*$ or $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$].

For instance let's take $g(x)=|x|$, we have $g'(x)=\pm 1\neq 0$ yet the minimum of $g$ is reached in $x=0$.

Thus $f(x,y)=(|y|+1)(x^2+1)$ on $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ this time would also have a global minimum in $(0,0)$ despite $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)\neq0$.

Intuitively your hypothesis says that $f(x,0)$ has a local minimum in $x=0$, and that locally $f(\cdot,y)$ is increasing in $y$ so $(0,0)$ is necessarily a local minimum for $f$.

---

Note that despite $f\in C^1(\mathbb R\times\mathbb R^{*+})$ where $y=0$ is excluded, since $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)$ exists we can extend $f$ into a function $\tilde f$ behaving as expected in a neighborhood of 
$(0,0)$ and write :

$\tilde f(x,y)=\underbrace{f(0,0)}_{\tilde f(0,0)}+x\;\underbrace{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)}_{0}+y\;\underbrace{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)}_{>0}+o(x,y)\ge \tilde f(0,0)\quad$ for $y>0$, thus realizing a local minimum of $\tilde f$.